# installrelease task fails due to KeytoolException

Tags: android, gradle

I generated a signed apk by going to build > generate signed apk. I then went to the app module settings > Signing (entered all the same information as I did before to create a signing config) > build types (assigned the signing config to the release build type, I checked to see if the installRelease task was available, it was. I checked the gradle file to see if all the keystore info was added, it was). However, when I run the installrelease task, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

    com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key() from store "/Users/joeljohnson/Downloads/ClockPlus-master/app/src/main/keystore.jks": No key with alias 'key()' found in keystore /Users/joeljohnson/Downloads/ClockPlus-master/app/src/main/keystore.jks
```

I tried deleting the keystore and signed apk, that didn't work among a few other things. How do I rectify the error?